# jQuery: How do I make an already open accordion slide collapse when I click on a different slide?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

Working codepen link: https://codepen.io/boingloings33/pen/PoXpLWR

I have a mostly functioning accordion that I'm struggling to make auto-collapse an open slide when I click the next one. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordion-1">
        <div class="head">
          <h2>Title 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p> lorem ipsum </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />

      <div class="accordion" id="accordion-2">
        <div class="head">
          <h2>Title 2</h2>
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down arrow"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
         <p> lorem ipsums </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function () {
  $(".head").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).parent().find(".arrow").toggleClass("arrow-animate");
    $(this).parent().find(".content").slideToggle(280);
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px #dbdbdb;
}

.accordion .head {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #563e6e;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.accordion .head:hover,
.accordion .active {
  background-color: #ffe77aff;
}
.accordion .content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the js code with the below code

```
jQuery(function () {
            $(".head").on("click", function () {              
                let isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');
                $(".head").removeClass('active');
                $(".head").parent().find(".content").slideUp(280);
                $(".head").parent().find(".arrow").removeClass("arrow-animate");
                if (isActive == false) {
                    $(this).addClass('active')
                    $(this).parent().find(".arrow").addClass("arrow-animate");
                    $(this).parent().find(".content").slideDown(280);
                }
            });
        });
```